# Store multiple radio button values in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, ejs, store, queryselector

I would like to store my test answers in an array in javascript. I created 50 questions with for loop, the user can choose between 4 radio buttons(answer). How could i store these answers in an array?

MY QUESTION CARDS

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < test.questions.length; i++){%>
  <br>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <%= test.questions[i].question%></h5>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" style="padding: 10px;">
          <li class="list-group-item"><input type="radio" name="one+<%=i%>" value="a"> <%= test.answers[0].answer%></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><input type="radio"  name="one+<%=i%>" value="b"> <%= test.answers[1].answer%></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"> <input type="radio" name="one+<%=i%>" value="c"> <%= test.answers[2].answer%></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><input type="radio" name="one+<%=i%>" value="d"> <%= test.answers[3].answer%></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><input type="radio" name="one+<%=i%>" value="e"> <%= test.answers[4].answer%></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<%}%>
```

WHAT I TRIED:

```
<script>
  var arr = []
  document.getElementById("confirm").addEventListener("click", function() {
      for (let index = 0; index < 51; index++) {
      
      var buttonName = "one" + index
     
      var buttChecked = document.querySelector('[name=buttonName]:checked')
      
      if (buttChecked != null) {
        arr.push(buttChecked.value)
      }
      console.log(arr)
    }
  })

</script>
```

Comment: Please show the ***rendered*** version of your HTML, not the code that creates the HTML.

Comment: looks like this: https://pasteboard.co/JOEeDgK.png @ScottMarcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use loop over an array containing the names of the radio button groups and get the value of the selected button in that group and add to the array:

```js
// Store the names of the radio button sets
let names = ["one","two","three"]
let results = [];

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  results = names.map(function(el){
    return document.querySelector("input[name='" + el + "']:checked").value;
  });
  
  console.log(results);
});
```

```html
<div class="question">
 <input type="radio" name="one" value="Choice A">Something |
 <input type="radio" name="one" value="Choice B">Something |
 <input type="radio" name="one" value="Choice C">Something
</div>

<div class="question">
 <input type="radio" name="two" value="Choice A">Something |
 <input type="radio" name="two" value="Choice B">Something |
 <input type="radio" name="two" value="Choice C">Something 
</div>

<div class="question">
 <input type="radio" name="three" value="Choice A">Something |
 <input type="radio" name="three" value="Choice B">Something |
 <input type="radio" name="three" value="Choice C">Something
</div>
<br>
<button>Collect Answers</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Handlebars JS, you can set up a question/answer data structure and navigate between questions, pre-selecting the answer.

```js
const randomSort = arr => arr.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
const mod = (n, m) => ((n % m) + m) % m;
const bump = (count, index, amount) => mod(index + amount, count);

// Handlebars helpers
Handlebars.registerHelper({
  ifEquals: function(arg1, arg2, options) {
    return arg1 === arg2 ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
  },
  randomEach: function(array, opts) {
    if (opts.data) data = Handlebars.createFrame(opts.data);
    return randomSort(array).map((e, i) => {
      if (data) data.index = i;
      return opts.fn(e, { data });
    }).join('');
  }
});

const compileTemplate = (selector) =>
  Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML);
  
const questions = [{
  prompt: "Which fruit is yellow?",
  answers: [ "Apple", "Banana", "Cantaloupe", "Date" ],
  answer: "Banana"
}, {
  prompt: "Which vegetable is red?",
  answers: [ "Carrot", "Pea", "Potato", "Tomato" ],
  answer: "Tomato"
}];

// Buttons
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#controls > .prev-btn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#controls > .next-btn');
const showBtn = document.querySelector('#controls > .show-btn');

let currQuestion = 0;
let answers = {};

const main = () => {
  rerender();
  prevBtn.addEventListener('click', handlePrev);
  nextBtn.addEventListener('click', handleNext);
  showBtn.addEventListener('click', handleShow);
};

const updateAnswers = (button) => {
  const form = button.closest('form');
  const value = form.elements.answer.value;
  answers[currQuestion] = value;
}

// Templates
const questionTemplate = compileTemplate('#question-template');
const infoTemplate = compileTemplate('#info-template');
const answersTemplate = compileTemplate('#answers-template');

// Rendering contexts
const questionEl = document.querySelector('#question');
const infoEl = document.querySelector('#info');
const answersEl = document.querySelector('#answers');

const navigateQuestion = (amount) => {
  currQuestion = bump(questions.length, currQuestion, amount);
};

const handlePrev = () => {
  navigateQuestion(-1);
  rerender();
};

const handleNext = () => {
  navigateQuestion(-1);
  rerender();
};

const handleShow = () => {
  const answerList = questions.map((question, index) => answers[index]);
  answersEl.innerHTML = answersTemplate(answerList);
};

const renderQuestion = (question) => {
  questionEl.innerHTML = questionTemplate(question);
  infoEl.innerHTML = infoTemplate({
    page: currQuestion + 1,
    count: questions.length
  });
};

const rerender = () =>
  renderQuestion(questions[currQuestion]);

main();
```

```css
.answer-field {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="question-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h2>{{prompt}}</h2>
  <form onsubmit="return false">
  {{#randomEach answers}}
    <div class="answer-field">
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="answer-{{@index}}"
        name="answer"
        value="{{.}}"
        {{#ifEquals . ../answer}}checked{{/ifEquals}}
      >
      <label for="answer-{{@index}}">{{.}}</label>
    </div>
  {{/randomEach}}
  <br />
  <button onclick="updateAnswers(this)">Submit</button>
  </form>
</script>
<script id="info-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <p>Question {{page}} of {{count}}</p>
</script>
<script id="answers-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <ol>
    {{#each .}}
      <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ol>
</script>
<div id="question"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="controls">
  <button class="prev-btn">Prev</button>
  <button class="show-btn">Show Answers</button>
  <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
</div>
<h2>Submitted Answers</h2>
<div id="answers"></div>
```